# Unsuccessful when testing a power entry module model in simulation

Tags: passive-networks

I'm trying to understand how [this power entry module](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/358/typ_5707-1275588.pdf) suppresses common mode interference. Here is the diagram:

[image]

I want to sort of make a simplistic EMC test in simulation just to see how the common mode is suppressed by this filter. In simulation I set the mains to zero and applied common mode voltage to see the effects better. The first circuit below is without module and the second one is with the module. I provided the correct values for the filter components in the diagram.

[image]

[image]

Is my model for this purpose correct? Why is there no difference between with and without module/filter cases at the output a, b,c and d?
How to model the test in simulation so we can see the difference between with and without module cases? It would be great if someone could make a simplistic test model just to see the idea for this module to see the effects of the module in simulation.

Comment: The -3dB point for an LC lowpass is L/2 pi C. Do the math and then try a frequency 10 times greater. Hint: it's a lot greater than what you're looking at now.

Comment: I tried with 100kHz and 1MegHz still exactly the same.

Comment: Did you do the math? What did it say? And by the way, R5 must returned to ground. Earth and signal ground may be tied together by a small(ish) impedance, but as you've shown it your common-mode signal is driving _everything_, which explains your results.

Comment: Yes you are right R5 was the problem. Now I can see attenuation at MHz levels of CM voltage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is there no difference between with and without module/filter
>   cases at the output a, b,c and d?

In your first circuit you say you made the mains voltage zero volts and this is equivalent to placing a short between lines a and b - hence Va and Vb are identical.

Now think about what happens in the 2nd scenario (mains also set to 0 volts). Why would you expect anything different?

> How to model he test in simulation so we can see the difference
>   between with and without module cases?

Your model is correct but too perfect and you don't have a load on the output. It's too perfect in that all the components that might give discrepancies are identical - try altering component values by 5% to simulate a real common-mode filter. You also need to assume that your load may not be perfectly balanced to ground and this will change things too.

Remember that the inductors in your top circuit are coupled and I see no evidence that you have done that in your 2nd sim. The coupling factor is also something you should vary - use a k value of about 0.95.

Comment: I added 1k load and still no difference. This filter obviously with my way of simulation never attenuate the CM voltage. Can you provide a simulation if possible? Im not able to figure it out until now:( Would be great to see how this works in simulation.

Comment: Read my answer and do the things that I suggested - imbalanced load, vary the component values by 5%, couple the inductors at 0.95.

Comment: Also note that R5 (1 ohm resistor) should go the earth of the common mode voltage.

Comment: Oh thats great you nailed it, R5 was the problem. After I corrected it I see significant decrease in CM voltage especially at MHz levels of frequency. Can we say which suppress the CM voltage here is Cy capacitors or also inductors? There is another version in the datasheet which has inductors but not Cy capacitors. I was wondering would that version never suppress CM voltages. Because in simulation it doesnt supress if I remove Cy capacitors.

Comment: The "medical version" I mean in the datasheet. That doesnt have Cy caps.

Comment: C and L are both suppressors. Without C in the module then it’s likely that C is assumed to be close to the patient interface on medical equipment.

Comment: Oh I see so the patient interface acts as Cy in that case. I was wondering how the CM currents will complete the loop without earth connection in medical type.